# static hostname из /etc/hostname во время загрузки переопределяется systemd на transient hostname

Tags: linux, сеть, systemd

Как установить `static hostname` 'good.host.name', чтобы он сохранялся при перезагрузке и не переопределялся на `transient hostname` 'bad.host.name'?

В `/etc/hostname` прописан 'good.host.name'. `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname good.host.name`, вопреки документации, устанавливает его только до перезагрузки.

```
openSUSE Tumbleweed | systemd-networkd + wpa_supplicant | systemd 228
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файл `/etc/sysctl.conf` или в любой файл с расширением `*.conf` в `/etc/sysctl.d` добавьте параметр `kernel.hostname = good.host.name`.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то `good.host.name` — это **доменное** имя, а не имя машины (*hostname*). Хотя современные версии программ и «справляются» с этой некорректностью, лучше всё же использовать (в файле `/etc/hostname`) «правильное» имя: `good`.

а доменное имя лучше указать в `/etc/hosts`:

```
ip-адрес good good.hostname
```

где `ip-адрес` — любой, закреплённый за [виртуальным сетевым интерфейсом *lo*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#.D0.92.D0.B8.D1.80.D1.82.D1.83.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D1.81.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.84.D0.B5.D0.B9.D1.81). Обычно закрепляется целая сеть `127/8`, поэтому можно использовать, например, `127.0.1.1`. только будьте внимательны — обычно в этом файле присутствует строка вида `127.0.0.1 localhost` — её лучше оставить в неизменном виде.

---

Вероятные же причины [переопределения имени машины](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228746/110559) в вашем случае:

- имя явно указано в сетевых настройках
- имя назначено dhcp-сервером
- машина виртуальная и имя назначается системой виртуализации

[Предложенное в соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550396/178576) обходное решение — вполне работоспособно, но, по сути, исправляет последствия, а не первопричину замены имени машины.

Comment: > Вообще-то good.host.name — это доменное имя, а не имя машины (hostname).
Есть сети, которые организованы вокруг общего домена (например domain.ru), и каждый компьютер в этой сети в hostname (vasya, petya, итд...) доменное имя составляет, как $hostname.$domain.
И по умолчанию, в `systemd`, как я понял, так и предполагается.
При этом, в более простых случаях, `domain` отсутствует, за ненадобностью и `hostname` является самодостаточным и сразу равен petya.domain.ru, по которому этот компьютер должен быть доступен, а главное, другим серверам он должен отвечать, что он, именно, petya.domain.ru

Comment: > Вероятные же причины...
В моём случае не одна из них. :-(
Единственная причина этого, как и многого другого, `Лёне Поттеру` так захотелось, и плевать ему на то, что всю жизнь этот параметр указывался в `/etc/hostname`. :-(

Comment: @IlyaIndigo, *другим серверам он должен отвечать, что он, именно, petya.domain.ru* — вероятно, вы здесь говорите о программах типа http-сервера, smtp-сервера и т.п.; у них несколько иное представление об этих вопросах, нежели у самой операционной системы: они могут «представляться» по-разному в зависимости от своих настроек — одна и та же программа может манипулировать разными **доменными** именами.

Comment: @IlyaIndigo, *Поттеру так захотелось* — вряд ли это поттер придумал заменять имя машины «good» на «bad». откуда берётся имя «bad» — вполне можно выяснить.